# How to configure url to WebSocket without Stomp having already Stomp WebSocket defined?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I have working Stomp WebSocket endpoint:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class WebSocketServerConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
...
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("myStompEndpoint");
    }
...
```

and want to add WebSocket endpoint without Stomp too:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class WsServerConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    private final MyTextWsHandler myTextWsHandler;

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry webSocketHandlerRegistry) {
        webSocketHandlerRegistry.addHandler(myTextWsHandler, "abcdef")
                .addInterceptors(myHandshakeInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Now the url to Stomp WebSocket is: `ws://localhost:8080/myStompEndpoint`. What is the url to WebSocket **without Stomp**?

Comment: The `abcdef` part is the path which your endpoint can be reached on. With STOMP the endpoint address doesn't change it just is an protocol over plain websockets.

Comment: The spring runs on `http://localhost:8080` then if I want to connect to above websocket I should connect to `ws://localhost:8080/abcdef` ? or make handshake on 
 `http://localhost:8080/abcdef` ? It doesn't work...

Comment: Connecting to `ws://localhost:8080/abcdef` should be all you need. If that doesn't work you aren't showing everything you are doing or what your interceptor isn't doing. Also stating *it doesn't work* is really helpful in solving your issue. We don't know what your handler is doing nor your interceptor or what kind of error you get on the client side.

Comment: I have configured stomp endpoint too. This is the problem I guess. I have edited my question, bro.

Comment: That would go beyond me, I'm not sure if you can configure both at the same time. When using STOMP I suspect everything is routed to/through that.